# How to define the name of the model in a function

Tags: python, function

I want to create a function where I loop over a number of parameters and record my results.  At the end I want to be able to access the best model.  What I don't seem to be able to figure out is how to define the name of the model in the function call.

```
def save_mod(mod_name):
    mod = xgb.train(
    params,
    dtrain,
    num_boost_round=999,
    evals=[(dval, "Val")],
    early_stopping_rounds=10)
    mod_name=mod
```

This runs but then the model isn't saved to the name I give it.  Attempting to access example tells me it doesn't exist, and if I drop the quotation marks in the definition, it doesn't run.

```
save_mod("example")
```

I'm sure this is a basic question, but I cannot find an answer.

Thank you,
J

Answer (score 2):

You are not saving the model, you are just assigning the `mod_name` string variable the `mod` xgb model.

Try this:

```
def save_mod(mod_name):
    mod = xgb.train(
        params,
        dtrain,
        num_boost_round=999,
        evals=[(dval, "Val")],
        early_stopping_rounds=10)    
    mod.save_model(mod_name)
    return mod

train_model = save_mod('train')
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are not returning anything from your function.

```
def save_mod(mod_name):
    .
    .
    .
    return mod_name
```